# Using ui-select2 with ng-repeat does not set the model correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, jquery-select2

### First, some background:

When using [`ui-select2`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2), you have to supply an `initSelection` function in the `select2` config object. If you don't, you'll get an error (but the functionality won't be affected. Everything will still work as expected).

To illustrate, see [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kYp5XODVcDm5ZwrrgFcm?p=preview). When you select an item from the dropdown menu, it'll work, but you'll get the following error:

> Error: cannot call val() if initSelection() is not defined

Adding an empty function to `initSelection` fixes the error. You can uncomment it in the above plunkr to see that.

---

### The problem:

When [using `ui-select2` in conjunction with `ng-repeat`](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENws6IH5XFd7flR2dM93?p=preview), it just doesn't update the model.

**Controller:**

```js
// for this demo, `users` is injected into the controller
$scope.users = users.slice(0, 2);

$scope.select2Config = {

    placeholder: 'Select User...',

    query: function ( options )
    {
        // `users` in this demo is injected into the controller.
        // in the real world this would be an ajax request
        options.callback({ results: users });
    },

    // Without initSelection, I get the above error.
    // Regardless, the model isn't updated.
    initSelection: angular.noop,

    formatSelection: select2format,

    formatResult: select2format,


};

function select2format ( user )
{
    return user.first + ' ' + user.last;
}
```

**View:**

```html
<ul> 
   <li ng-repeat="user in users">
       <input type="text" ng-model="user" ui-select2="select2Config">
   </li> 
</ul>
```

When selecting an item from the dropdown list, the model isn't updated. If there's no `initSelection` in the config I get the above error, but adding it still doesn't update the model.

[Here's a plunkr demonstrating the above](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENws6IH5XFd7flR2dM93?p=preview).

---

### The question:

How do I make `ui-select2` update the model in an `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using inheritance:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jyJaYU4DQX1LROD6nQaw?p=preview

Also I you were calling "user in users" on the ng-repeat but then also setting the ng-model to "user".  I am not sure why.

As to initSelection behavior, I do not have an answer.

---

## edit

I updated the plunker.  The ng-repeat directive creates a new scopes - true, but all of its children (or repeated items) are siblings. You had bound "user" (that was being defined/transcluded by ng-repeat) to the ng-model of each select (and expecting that the "users" array would be updated if you changed the model).

I believe ng-repeat is a one way binding [top down](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js)

Therefor what I showed was correct but admittedly lazy.  I bound both selects to the same model but I just as easily bound them to seperate properties on the "selected" object using $index.

Point is: if you want two way binding then write a new directive, but it is easier to do something similar to what I show.

PS: In practice I populate a "lookups" object that has some arrays for the select/pull-downs and use a seperate object called "user" that holds what the user has selected.  This is pretty much pulled right out of the (older) documentation.

Comment: You're not using the repeater scope. You have a separate `selection` object on the scope, which you just have 2 `select2` instances for no good reason. Changing one of them changes the other. Your demo is not even remotely related to what I've outlined above.